# Select all rows except that match the condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a condition where I need to fetch all rows from master table. Except those rows whose condition is satisfied in child table ignore them, also fetch rows from master table which are not there in child table.

Following are the sample tables along with the data,
Table **Foo**

```
Foo_Id  Foo_Name
101        A
102        B
103        C
104        D
105        E
```

Table **Bar**

```
Bar_Id  Foo_id  Bar_Status
21        101    Yes
22        101    No
23        102    No
24        103    Yes
25        103    No
26        103    NA
27        104    No
28        104    NA
```

Suppose I need all Foo_name from table **Foo**, but the value of Foo_id in table **Bar** should not be 'Yes'. Also fetch Foo_id which are not present in **Bar** but present in **Foo**

Expected output,

```
Foo_Id  Foo_Name
102     B
104     D
105     E
```

As 'A' & 'C' have value 'Yes' they are filtered out.

This is what I tried,

```
Select F.Foo_id, F.Foo_Name
From Foo F LEFT JOIN Bar B on F.Foo_id = B.Foo_id AND B.Bar_staus != 'Yes'
WHERE B.Foo_id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer should not contain subquery

Comment: Have you tried anything?  There are several ways to do this -- look up `not exists`...

Comment: @sgeddes, I have added query which I have tried

Comment: @sgeddes For whatever reason OP is not allowed to use a subquery.

Comment: Your query was extremely close -- instead of not equal, you should be using equals and instead of is not null use is null...

Comment: To paraphrase @sgeddes: You *do* want to look only at the "yes" rows. And you only want to keep the ones that then didn't match.

Comment: @shawnt00 - that won't filter out Foo_Id = 101, which has both a Yes and No record in Bar.

Comment: @devlincarnate The join will match on the Yes and so the `Foo_id` will not be null and it will be filtered: we want to keep only the nulls (what I meant by "that then didn't match".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join only on the *Yes* rows and then keep only the ones that didn't find a match:

```
select F.Foo_id, F.Foo_Name
from
    Foo F left outer join Bar B
        on F.Foo_id = B.Foo_id and B.Bar_status = 'Yes'
where B.Foo_id is null
```

@sgeddes Described this answer in comments but perhaps it wasn't clear how to implement the suggestion. If it's possible to have multiple *Yes* values in B then you'll want to add `distinct`.

Comment: thanks a lot shawnt00 & @sgeddes it worked as expected,

Answer (score -1):

What comes to mind is `not in` or `not exists`:

```
select f.*
from foo f
where not exists (select 1
                  from bar b
                  where b.foo_id = f.foo_id and b.bar_status = 'Yes'
                 );
```

Comment: @martin_vai7 Why did you put a restriction on subqueries and then accept an answer that used one without any further comments above?

Comment: Works as expected, thanks a lot @Gordon Linoff :), but I am looking solution without subquery

Comment: @martin_vai7 . . . Why would you add such an artificial condition to a problem?

Comment: @GordonLinoff My first guess was that this is related to homework. I did not downvote your answer though.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not suppose to use subquery as per our coding guidelines. Our organization doesn't allow us to use subqueries that's why I have added the condition. Neither did I downvote your answer